# Json - stringify so that arrays are on one line

Tags: json, stringify

Is it possible to stringify a JSON object to look like this, with arrays in one line - not indented

```
{
    "Repeat": {
        "Name": [["Top_level","All"],[[1,1]]],
        "Link": [["Top_level"],[[1,1]]]
    },
    "Delete": ["Confirm","Cancel"],
    "Move": ["Up","Down"],
    "Number": ["Ascending","Descending"]
}
```

Answer (score 21):

Try this:

```
var obj = {"Repeat": {"Name":[["Top_level","All"],[[1,1]]],"Link": [["Top_level"],[[1,1]]]},"Delete": ["Confirm","Cancel"],"Move": ["Up","Down"],"Number": ["Ascending","Descending"]};

JSON.stringify(obj,function(k,v){
   if(v instanceof Array)
      return JSON.stringify(v);
   return v;
},2);
```

Result:

```
"{
  "Repeat": {
    "Name": "[[\"Top_level\",\"All\"],[[1,1]]]",
    "Link": "[[\"Top_level\"],[[1,1]]]"
  },
  "Delete": "[\"Confirm\",\"Cancel\"]",
  "Move": "[\"Up\",\"Down\"]",
  "Number": "[\"Ascending\",\"Descending\"]"
}"
```

Comment: Thanks that looks more like it should be. I will try it out in good time.  What does k do?

Comment: k and v are the key/values for object that gets passed in to that function, in this case k doesn't do anything

Comment: The arrays come out as single strings; is there an equally smart way to return them to arrays? If so your answer definitely gets the tick

Comment: It prints out like this:` "images": "[\"2\",\"3\",\"4\",\"5\",\"6\",\"7\"]"`

Comment: This part gets a little tricky, what I did when I implemented it was to strip out the quotes and backslashes with regex. As for the arrays you can make a recursive method that loops through every time an array is detected and tack it on the end of output string. It can get a little messy from here.

Comment: The regex seems OK but the arrays may contain strings so would have to be backslashes, "[ and ]" ... will try it out ... all in good time!

Comment: It seems adding these sorts out the punctuation problems:`html = html.split('"[').join("[");
html = html.split(']"').join("]");
html = html.split('\\"').join('"');
html = html.split('""').join('"'"'");`

Answer (score 15):

Taking the answers from [ericbowden](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18452766/6828099) and [bigp](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42381024/6828099), I produced the below function which allows me to pretty print JSON while keeping an array on a single line and keeping the array in array form instead of converting it to a string.

```
function prettyPrintArray(json) {
  if (typeof json === 'string') {
    json = JSON.parse(json);
  }
  output = JSON.stringify(json, function(k,v) {
    if(v instanceof Array)
      return JSON.stringify(v);
    return v;
  }, 2).replace(/\\/g, '')
        .replace(/\"\[/g, '[')
        .replace(/\]\"/g,']')
        .replace(/\"\{/g, '{')
        .replace(/\}\"/g,'}');

  return output;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer - this works great.  Here I have adapted your function to pass JSLint: 

    ```const prettyPrintArray = obj => JSON.stringify( obj, (key, val) => (val instanceof Array) ? JSON.stringify(val) : val, 2).replace(/\\/g, '').replace(/\[/g, '[').replace(/\]/g,']').replace(/\{/g, '{').replace(/\}/g,'}'); ```

Comment: If you have a string value that ends with a square or curly bracket this will not produce a valid JSON string as the replace calls at the bottom, will replace the string's closing quotation mark.

Answer (score 11):

If you mean to display short arrays as single lines, consider using [json-stringify-pretty-compact](https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-stringify-pretty-compact). It produces results looking as follows:

```
{
  "bool": true,
  "short array": [1, 2, 3],
  "long array": [
    {"x": 1, "y": 2},
    {"x": 2, "y": 1},
    {"x": 1, "y": 1},
    {"x": 2, "y": 2}
  ]
}
```

Comment: This works pretty well once you get it going. It's an odd process though - or maybe I don't know what I'm doing... It installs easily with npm. After that, to get it working, your script tag needs to point to 'index.js' (There isn't a json-stringify-pretty-compact js file). Then you have to comment out the last line, like this: `//module.exports = stringify`. Then you can use it in place of JSON.stringify, like this: `stringify(jSONObject, null, 2)`. Indeed it does make JSON look much better.

Answer (score 8):

Another approach which I took:

```
obj => JSON.stringify(obj, (k,v) => Array.isArray(v) ? JSON.stringify(v) : v, 2)
.replace(/"\[[^"\]]*]"/g, r => JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(r)).substr(1).slice(0,-1))
```

*Array must not contain strings (notice the " in the not contains inside the regex), if you remove it it will catch key,values of:
`"[": "[1,2,3,4]",`

### Update 2020-03 - I worked out a more stable solution

```js
const obj = {
  "first_name": "John",
  "last_name": "Smith",
  "age": 21,
  "hobbies": [ "programming", "workout", null, undefined, 24, "\"has double quotes\"" ],
  "nested": {
    "arr": [ "one", "two", "three" ],
  },
  "nested_arr": [
    "first as string",
    {
      "latin": [ "alpha", "beta", "[gamma]" ]
    },
    null
  ]
};

const stringify = (obj, indent = 2) => 
  JSON.stringify(obj, (key, value) => {
    if (Array.isArray(value) && !value.some(x => x && typeof x === 'object')) {
      return `\uE000${JSON.stringify(value.map(v => typeof v === 'string' ? v.replace(/"/g, '\uE001') : v))}\uE000`;
    }
    return value;
  }, indent).replace(/"\uE000([^\uE000]+)\uE000"/g, match => match.slice(2, -2).replace(/\\"/g, '"').replace(/\uE001/g, '\\\"'));

console.log(stringify(obj));
```

Comment: Do you think it would get this result: www.glasier.hk - select JSON

Comment: For general purpose prettying I would suggest using a third party library as suggested by @Piotr Migdal

Comment: The `substr` method has since been [deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr). Instead one can use `match.substring(2, match.length - 2)`.

Answer (score 8):

Another modern answer for an old question: Take a look at [FracturedJson](https://j-brooke.github.io/FracturedJson/).  That link will take you to the web version, but it's available as a commandline app, and libraries for .NET and JS.

FracturedJson will inline arrays/objects as long as they're neither too long nor too complex.  It can likewise split arrays into multiple lines with multiple items per line.

Here's an example using the default settings, but you can adjust them to whatever works best for your data.

```
{
    "SimpleItem": 77,
    "ComplexObject": {
        "Subthing1": {"X": 55, "Y": 19, "Z": -4},
        "Subthing2": { "Q": null, "W": [-2, -1, 0, 1] },
        "Distraction": [[], null, null]
    },
    "ShortArray": ["blue", "blue", "orange", "gray"],
    "LongArray": [
        2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 
        79, 83, 89, 97, 101, 103, 107, 109, 113, 127, 131, 137, 139, 149, 151, 157, 
        163, 167, 173, 179, 181, 191, 193, 197, 199, 211, 223, 227, 229, 233, 239, 241, 
        251, 257, 263, 269, 271, 277, 281, 283, 293
    ],
    "LongArray2": [
        [19, 2],
        [3, 8],
        [14, 0],
        [9, 9],
        [9, 9],
        [0, 3],
        [10, 1],
        [9, 1],
        [9, 2],
        [6, 13],
        [18, 5],
        [4, 11],
        [12, 2]
    ]
}
```

Disclosure: I'm the author of FracturedJson.  It's open source under an MIT license.

Comment: I think this is the best solution. thanks!!

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
JSON.stringify(obj,function(k,v){
   if(v instanceof Array)
      return JSON.stringify(v);
   return v;
},4)
.replace(/"\[/g, '[')
.replace(/\]"/g, ']')
.replace(/\\"/g, '"')
.replace(/""/g, '"');
```

Comment: I tried but this does not work with multi level objects

Answer (score 2):

Mind you this uses `lodash` to detect Arrays and Objects, here's another method that will keep the "leaf" objects compact on one line:

```
_.jsonPretty = function(obj, indent) {
    if(!indent) indent = 2;

    return JSON.stringify(obj, function(k,v) {
        //Check if this is a leaf-object with no child Arrays or Objects:
        for(var p in v) {
            if(_.isArray(v[p]) || _.isObject(v[p])) {
                return v;
            }
        }

        return JSON.stringify(v);

        //Cleanup the escaped strings mess the above generated:
    }, indent).replace(/\\/g, '')
        .replace(/\"\[/g, '[')
        .replace(/\]\"/g,']')
        .replace(/\"\{/g, '{')
        .replace(/\}\"/g,'}');
};
```

And just use it like this:

```
_.jsonPretty(yourObjectToStringify);
```

Here's an example **before**...

```
{
  "type": "light-item",
  "name": "Waiting",
  "ringSeqLooping": true,
  "ringSeqHoldLast": false,
  "ringSteps": [
    {
      "type": "light-step",
      "time": 1,
      "audioClipName": "Off",
      "audioVolume": 1,
      "lights": [
        {
          "state": "FadeOn",
          "color": "#fff"
        },
        {
          "state": "Off",
          "color": "#fff"
        },
        {
          "state": "Off",
          "color": "#fff"
        },
        {
          "state": "Off",
          "color": "#fff"
        },
        {
          "state": "Off",
          "color": "#fff"
        },
        {
          "state": "Off",
          "color": "#fff"
        },
        {
          "state": "Off",
          "color": "#fff"
        },
        {
          "state": "Off",
          "color": "#fff"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "light-step",
      "time": "0.5",
      "audioClipName": "Off",
      "audioVolume": 1,
      "lights": [
        {
          "state": "FadeOff",
          "color": "#fff"
        },
        {
          "state": "Off",
          "color": "#fff"
        },
        {
          "state": "Off",
          "color": "#fff"
        },
        {
          "state": "Off",
          "color": "#fff"
        },
        {
          "state": "Off",
          "color": "#fff"
        },
        {
          "state": "Off",
          "color": "#fff"
        },
        {
          "state": "Off",
          "color": "#fff"
        },
        {
          "state": "Off",
          "color": "#fff"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "stripSeqLooping": true,
  "stripSeqHoldLast": false,
  "stripSteps": [
    {
      "type": "light-step",
      "time": "2",
      "audioClipName": "Off",
      "audioVolume": 1,
      "lights": [
        {
          "state": "Off",
          "color": "#fff"
        },
        {
          "state": "Off",
          "color": "#fff"
        },
        {
          "state": "Off",
          "color": "#fff"
        },
        {
          "state": "FadeOn",
          "color": "#fff"
        },
        {
          "state": "FadeOn",
          "color": "#fff"
        },
        {
          "state": "Off",
          "color": "#fff"
        },
        {
          "state": "Off",
          "color": "#fff"
        },
        {
          "state": "Off",
          "color": "#fff"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "light-step",
      "time": "2",
      "audioClipName": "Off",
      "audioVolume": 1,
      "lights": [
        {
          "state": "Off",
          "color": "#fff"
        },
        {
          "state": "Off",
          "color": "#fff"
        },
        {
          "state": "Off",
          "color": "#fff"
        },
        {
          "state": "FadeOff",
          "color": "#fff"
        },
        {
          "state": "FadeOff",
          "color": "#fff"
        },
        {
          "state": "Off",
          "color": "#fff"
        },
        {
          "state": "Off",
          "color": "#fff"
        },
        {
          "state": "Off",
          "color": "#fff"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

... and **after**:

```
{
  "type": "light-item",
  "name": "Waiting",
  "ringSeqLooping": "true",
  "ringSeqHoldLast": "false",
  "ringSteps": [
    {
      "type": "light-step",
      "time": "1",
      "audioClipName": "Off",
      "audioVolume": "1",
      "lights": [
        {"state":"FadeOn","color":"#fff"},
        {"state":"Off","color":"#fff"},
        {"state":"Off","color":"#fff"},
        {"state":"Off","color":"#fff"},
        {"state":"Off","color":"#fff"},
        {"state":"Off","color":"#fff"},
        {"state":"Off","color":"#fff"},
        {"state":"Off","color":"#fff"}
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "light-step",
      "time": "0.5",
      "audioClipName": "Off",
      "audioVolume": "1",
      "lights": [
        {"state":"FadeOff","color":"#fff"},
        {"state":"Off","color":"#fff"},
        {"state":"Off","color":"#fff"},
        {"state":"Off","color":"#fff"},
        {"state":"Off","color":"#fff"},
        {"state":"Off","color":"#fff"},
        {"state":"Off","color":"#fff"},
        {"state":"Off","color":"#fff"}
      ]
    }
  ],
  "stripSeqLooping": "true",
  "stripSeqHoldLast": "false",
  "stripSteps": [
    {
      "type": "light-step",
      "time": "2",
      "audioClipName": "Off",
      "audioVolume": "1",
      "lights": [
        {"state":"Off","color":"#fff"},
        {"state":"Off","color":"#fff"},
        {"state":"Off","color":"#fff"},
        {"state":"FadeOn","color":"#fff"},
        {"state":"FadeOn","color":"#fff"},
        {"state":"Off","color":"#fff"},
        {"state":"Off","color":"#fff"},
        {"state":"Off","color":"#fff"}
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "light-step",
      "time": "2",
      "audioClipName": "Off",
      "audioVolume": "1",
      "lights": [
        {"state":"Off","color":"#fff"},
        {"state":"Off","color":"#fff"},
        {"state":"Off","color":"#fff"},
        {"state":"FadeOff","color":"#fff"},
        {"state":"FadeOff","color":"#fff"},
        {"state":"Off","color":"#fff"},
        {"state":"Off","color":"#fff"},
        {"state":"Off","color":"#fff"}
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Ugh... I did notice some flaws just now (with booleans & numbers in particular) where it puts double-quotes around it. I guess it's up to you to decide if it's safe to do more global replacements across the entire JSON string to remove those edge cases.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution I worked out which may be useful as a basis for doing something similar:

```
function labTab(ind){
    var tab,com,a;
    tab = "\t";
    com = [];
    for(a = 0; a < ind; a+=1){
        com.push(tab)
    }
    return com.join("");
}

function nsetEntry(tab,o,obj){
    return tab + '"'+ o + '":' + JSON.stringify(obj[o]);
}

function nsetObject(tab,o,obj,arr,ind){
    var start;
    start = tab + '"'+ o + '":{'; 
    return [start,nsetConstructor(obj[o],arr,ind)].join("\n") + "\n" + tab +"}"; 
}

function nsetConstructor(obj,arr,ind){
    var narr,tab,o,entry;
    narr = [];
    ind += 1;
    tab = labTab(ind);
    for(o in obj){
        if(obj[o].constructor === Object){
            entry = nsetObject(tab,o,obj,arr,ind);
            narr.push(entry); 
        }
        else{
            entry = nsetEntry(tab,o,obj);
            narr.push(entry);
        }
    }
    return narr.join(",\n");
}

function nsetLevels(obj,arr,ind){
    var o,start,tab;
    tab = labTab(ind);
    for(o in obj){
        if(obj[o].constructor === Object){
            entry = nsetObject(tab,o,obj,arr,ind);
            arr.push(entry); 
        }
        else{
            entry = nsetEntry(tab,o,obj);   
            arr.push(entry);
        }
    }
        return arr.join(",\n");
}

function nsetSave(){
    var json,o,ind,tab,obj,start,head,tail;
    json = [];
    for(o in nset){
        ind = 1;
        tab = labTab(ind);
        start = tab + '"'+ o + '":{';
        ind = 2;
        tab = labTab(ind);
        obj = nset[o];
        json.push([start,nsetLevels(obj,[],ind)].join("\n"))
    }
    head = "{\n";
    tail = "\n\t}\n}"
    FW.Write([head,json.join("\n\t},\n"),tail].join(""),"xset.json")
}
```

I could not figure out how to do replace as some members go down five levels,so I recreated the whole thing. The solution is not so hot but I got what I wanted to achieve - sample below:

```
    "Key":{
        "Label":{
            "Change":["Input"],
            "Repeat":{
                "Name":[["Top_level","All"],[[1,1]]],
                "Link":[["Top_level"],[[1,1]]]
            },
            "Delete":["Confirm","Cancel"],
            "Move":["Up","Down"],
            "Number":["Ascending","Descending"]
        },
        "Class":{
            "Change":["Input"]
        },
```

Answer (score 1):

I use JSON format for my app's configuration files. They are quite dissimilar and big enough, so different formatting rules are required to make them look better and readable. Unfortunately, provided answers are not flexible enough so I've made my own implementation called [perfect-json](https://www.npmjs.com/package/perfect-json) to beautify JSON.

Consider that you want to format object in the question like this:

```json
{
  "Repeat": {
    "Name": [
      ["Top_level", "All"],
      [[1, 1]]
    ],
    "Link": [
      ["Top_level"],
      [[1, 1]]
    ]
  },
  "Delete": ["Confirm", "Cancel"],
  "Move": ["Up", "Down"],
  "Number": [
    "Ascending",
    "Descending"
  ]
}
```

With `perfect-json` it can be achieved:

```js
import perfectJson from 'perfect-json';

const obj = {
  Repeat: {
    Name: [['Top_level', 'All'], [[1, 1]]],
    Link: [['Top_level'], [[1, 1]]]
  },
  Delete: ['Confirm', 'Cancel'],
  Move: ['Up', 'Down'],
  Number: ['Ascending', 'Descending']
};

console.log(perfectJson(obj, {
  singleLine: ({ key, path, depth }) => {
    if (['Delete', 'Move'].includes(key)) {
      return true;
    }
    if (depth >= 3 && ['Name', 'Link'].includes(path[1])) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
}));
```

It's also easy to place each array on a single line as asked in the question:

```js
console.log(perfectJson(obj, {
  indent: 4,
  singleLine: ({ value }) => Array.isArray(value)
}));
```

Comment: Just in time for the question's tenth anniversary. Give me time to absorb it; I am sure it deserves an upvote.

Answer (score 1):

I use prettier.

First install it:

```
npm i prettier
```

Then use it:

```js
const prettier = require("prettier")

const obj = {"Repeat": {"Name":[["Top_level","All"],[[1,1]]],"Link": [["Top_level"],[[1,1]]]},"Delete": ["Confirm","Cancel"],"Move": ["Up","Down"],"Number": ["Ascending","Descending"]};

const json = prettier.format(JSON.stringify(obj), { parser: "json" });
```